Why is the 74L86 pinout different from the 7486 and 74LS86?
Someone mentioned in a forum that the 74L86 pinout is different from the 74LS86. A quick look at a TI datasheet shows that it covers the the 54 and 74 versions of the '86, 'LS86A and 'S86, and all DIP versions of those seem to have the same pinout.
Digging around, I found this datasheet that seems to indicate that '86, 'S86, 'LS86, and 'S86 from many different manufacturers use the same pinout, but for 'L86 parts from TI and NSC (the only two vendors covered), there are actually two different pinouts (both different from the '86) depending on the packaging: C and P (presumably ceramic and plastic) use the second pinout, and M and CF (which I do not know the meanings of) use the third pinout.
What is the reason for this, and where else should I be watchful for differences like this in 7400-series parts? (And what are M and CF packaging?)

I don't recall meeting this problem in the last 60 years. That could be a memory issue but I don't think so :-). Transistor pinouts have been known to vary. || If I was building anything with 74xyy (which is becoming increasingly less likely) I'd very probably check the datasheet for each part in any case. Other parametrs than pinout are more liable to vary between brands and packages.

Yes, I've seen that transistor pinouts vary, even on devices from different manufacturers that have or seem to have the same part number, so I now check pinouts carefully when not using the exact transistor specified somewhere. I wasn't aware that this applies to 74xxyy parts, though, and this is the first example I've ever seen of it.

I'm afraid this type of question isn't particularly answerable: an authoritative response requires inside knowledge from the company(ies) that created those footprints. There's very little on the internet today, let alone in databooks and contemporary appnotes, that will answer this. It seems you're not the first to ask [anywhere]: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/sdtoca/74l86_has_different_pinout_than_74ls86/ You might get lucky, with a retired employee seeing this question or something, but I wouldn't count on it. (Not to say it's a bad question, just setting expectations.)

Confirmation is easy enough; consider the 1981 TTL databook for example: http://www.bitsavers.org/components/ti/_dataBooks/1981_TI_The_TTL_Data_Book_For_Design_Engineers_2ed.pdf (p.322) Perhaps the relevant bulletin, or release/introduction docs, provide some explanation -- but these will be hard to find today.

The 7402 NORs have a non-standardized pinout.  I always attributed it to different manufacturers design decisions.  As in, there was a whole line of parts with that pinout. There was some reason to adopt it over the 7400 pinout, when standardization occurred.

Plastic is N, Ceramic is J.  "C" and "P" may refer to something else -- for example, may explicitly identify pinout variants

It's not really anything particular to the 74xx86, nor the 74L part: Texas Instruments made a wholes series of "centre-power" flat-pack pinouts called T (gold-plated pins) and W (tinned leads).  The pinout drawing makes it look like a typical 14-pin DIL, but it's not.
The databook shows that many but not all 74-series were available in these flat-pack forms, but I don't think I've ever seen one.
The ones you have to worry about are the few conventional DIL packages with variant pinouts.  I confess I'm amazed, and I'll guess it's a compatibility issue with some other manufacturer.  This table is what I found to be the variations.  You can see how TI shows it in their databook below.



Device
Pinout A
Pinout B
Function




74X01
plain, LS
H
quad 2-input NAND OC


74X51
plain, H, S
L, LS
AND-OR-INVERT


74X53
plain
H
expandable 4-wide AND-OR-INVERT


74X54
plain
H
4-wide AND-OR-INVERT


74X55
H
L, LS
2-wide 4-input AND-OR-INVERT


74X78
H
L, LS
dual J-K flip flop


74X85
plain, LS, S
L
4-bit magnitude comparitor


74X86
plain, LS, S
L
quad 2-bit XOR


74X93
plain, LS
L
4-bit binary counter


74X95
plain, LS
L
4-bit shift register



From Texas Instruments TTL Data Book, 2 ed. 1981:
We see that the 01 and 86 parts have variants both in DIL and flatpack, just to catch us out!


This is what the flatpack looks like:


Brilliant work! I had totally missed the DIL vs. flatpack thing.
